# Sublime Text 2 - Auto-complete/suggest from other files

Tags: sublimetext

Say I have 2 files:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

and

```
123
456
f[want autocomplete here]
```

If I type `1` in the 2nd file, Sublime will suggest `123`. But if I type `f` it wont suggest anything. I want it to suggest `foo` like it would if I were inside the first file.

It seems like this should be simple (each buffer can autocomplete, so searching all of them can't be so hard) but I haven't been able to find a plugin that does this.

Comment: Have you tried asking at the [forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/)? I think I've seen that question there before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wrote a plugin that does this:

```
import sublime_plugin, sublime

class AutocompleteAll(sublime_plugin.EventListener):

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        window = sublime.active_window()
        # get results from each tab
        results = [v.extract_completions(prefix) for v in window.views() if v.buffer_id() != view.buffer_id()]
        results = [(item,item) for sublist in results for item in sublist] #flatten
        results = list(set(results)) # make unique
        results.sort() # sort
        return results
```

Answer (score 104):

I've implemented the same idea and published it as a package so it can be installed directly from within Sublime with Package Control:

Press ctrl+shift+p (Windows, Linux) or cmd+shift+p (OS X) to open the Command Pallete. Start typing 'install' to select 'Package Control: Install Package', then search for AllAutocomplete and select it.

Code is here: https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete

Comment: Wow! That works great. Found one bug - it does not detect and autocompletes classes names if class have ``-`` in it. Everything else works great.

Comment: @Rafal Glad you like it. To make names with dashes work you might need to remove - from word_separators in your Preferences file (open from menu Preferences > Settings-User). If you think you found a bug please open an issue on https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete.

Comment: "I've implemented it". @alienhard answer like a king. Thanks!